# Kubernetes service for pod with hostnetworking

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I've a pod with hostnetworking enabled. The host has multiple interfaces like eth0,eth1,eth2,lo. Now when I configure service with type clusterIP and selector "app:my-app" , what will be the endpoints associated with svc? I see it's selecting the IP associated with eth0(this network is part of kubernetes subnet). Is there a way to tell the service to pick IP associated with any particular interface?

Comment: What network plugin (eg. Calico, Flannel...) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- `kubectl get endpoints` will show available endpoints for services
- we can edit the endpoint directly with ip address of any particular interface

```
     1.  kubectl edit endpoints <svcname>
     2.  change the `ip` field with the desired eth interface ip address.
```